# How do I set a universal tab size in Bluefish text editor?

Tags: ubuntu, text-editor, tab-size

I've started using the Bluefish text editor a little while ago, and it has some pretty good merits, but one of the biggest annoyances it has is it's default tab size.

In Bluefish, 'tab width' is the number of space characters a tab is set equal to. This isn't what I'm talking about. 'Tab size' is the actual width on the screen the tab is displayed as. By default, whenever I open a file, the tab size is such that a tab appears approximately the same as a space character (actually ~1.5 space chars), which I just can't deal with. So, I change it, by Documents->Tab Size->Increase, until it's big enough for me. That's all fine, but it only changes the look of this one file, while it's open.

If I open another file, or close the one I just changed and open another, it's back to the default of looking the same as a single space character.

Is there some way I can set Bluefish's default tab size to something bigger, so I don't have to keep changing it all the time? A variable in a config file maybe, or menu option I haven't found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this was posted a long time ago but I was just googling this and have been looking around for ages.

In bluefish 2.2.6:

### Edit > Preferences > Initial document settings

It's at the bottom of the window.

[image: A screenshot to show the location of the tab settings]

Answer (score 0):

Additional: If your project, like mine, doesn't accept the changes then you can edit the .bfproject file and change the line:

```
editor_tab_width: <new tab size>
```

That works.